# Regex matching too many groups

Tags: c#, regex

I'm using C# Regex class. I'm trying to split two strings from one. The source (input) string is constructed in following way:

first part must match PO|P|S|[1-5] (in regex syntax).

second part can be VP|GZ|GAR|PP|NAD|TER|NT|OT|LO (again, regex syntax). Second part can occur zero or one time.

Acceptable examples are "PO" (one group), "POGAR" (both groups PO+GAR), "POT" (P+OT)...

So I've use the following regex expression:

```
Regex r = new Regex("^(?<first>PO|P|S|[1-5])(?<second>VP|GZ|GAR|PP|NAD|TER|NT|OT|LO)?$");
Match match = r.Match(potentialToken);
```

**When potentialToken is "PO", it returns 3 groups!** How come? I am expecting just one group (first).

match.Groups are {"PO","PO",""}

Named groups are OK - match.Groups["first"] returns 1 instance, while match.Groups["second"].Success is false.

Comment: There seems to be a syntax error in your regular expression - there should probably be a `<` in front of `second`. Also, have you checked the `Success` values of the groups when retrieving `match.Groups` by index?

Comment: I've fixed the syntax as you noticed (thanks). Success values in match.Groups are {"PO",true;"PO",true;"",false}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the numbered groups, the first group is always the complete matched (sub)string (cf. [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - "the first element of the GroupCollection object returned by the Groups property contains a string that matches the entire regular expression pattern"), i.e. in your case `PO`.

The second element in `Groups` is the capture of your first named group, and the third element is the capture of your second named group - just like the two captures you can retrieve by name. If you check `Success` of the numbered groups, you will see that the last element (the one matching your second named group) has a `Success` value of `false`, as well. You can interpret this as "the group exists, but it did not match anything".

To confirm this, have a look at the output of this testing code:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Regex r = new Regex("^(?<first>PO|P|S|[1-5])(?<second>VP|GZ|GAR|PP|NAD|TER|NT|OT|LO)?$");
        Match match = r.Match("PO");

        for (int i = 0; i < match.Groups.Count; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}; {2}", i, match.Groups[i].Success, match.Groups[i].Value));
        }
    }
}
```

You can run it [here](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_csharp_online.php).

Answer (score 1):

RegularExpression will always have one group which is "Group 0" at index 0 even though you don't have any capturing groups.

"Group 0" will be equal to whole match the regex has made(`Match.Value`).

Then in your case you get 3 groups because `"Group 0" + "Group first" + "Group second"`. As mentioned "Group second" is an optional group so when it doesn't take part in subject .Net regex engine marks `"Group second".Success = false`. I don't see anything surprise here. This is the expected behavior.